# Load a js file using onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file that has more than one function.

I found this script online that allows me to call a js file by clicking on a button.

Assuming that the js file is called black.js, is there a better way to write this code or another script that allows me to call the entire javascript file because I have more than one script, and I cannot end the script I call.

I tried :

`return false;`
Here is the script :

```
var btn = document.getElementById('img');
var loaded = false;
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(loaded) return;
    loaded = true;
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    script.src = 'black.js';
    var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);

    if(window.addEventListener) {
      script.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        // now you can access the functions inside the JS file
      });
    } else {
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") {
          // access the functions in the JS file
          script.onreadystatechange = null;
        }
      };
    }
});
```

This is my Javascript file

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
coord = document.getElementById('coord'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), // get 2D context
imgCat = new Image(),
arr = [];

imgCat.src =   'http://c.wearehugh.com/dih5/openclipart.org_media_files_johnny_automatic_1360.png';
imgCat.onload = function() { // wait for image load
    ctx.drawImage(imgCat, 0, 0); // draw imgCat on (0, 0)
};

var mousedown = false;
$(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        ajax_request();
    });
});

ctx.strokeStyle = '#14890E';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    arr = [];
    var pos = fixPosition(e, canvas);
    mousedown = true;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    return false;
};

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
var pos = fixPosition(e, canvas);
    // coord.innerHTML = '(' + pos.x + ',' + pos.y + ')';
    if (mousedown) {
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
       arr.push([pos.x, pos.y])
    }
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    // $('#coords').html(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
};


function fixPosition(e, gCanvasElement) {
    var x;
    var y;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
      x = e.pageX;
      y = e.pageY;
    }
    else { 
      x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
          document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
          document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    } 
    x -= gCanvasElement.offsetLeft;
    y -= gCanvasElement.offsetTop;
    return {x: x, y:y};
}
```

Comment: If i understand correctly what you want to do, you could take a look at http://yepnopejs.com/

Comment: This code is working fine, but for some reason it never ends as I have other buttons calling other script files. I am trying to find another way to call the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your code at hand, but try the following replacing the angle bracket values with the appropriate ones.

```
// makes sure html has loaded before element query
// ommit if html has already loaded
window.onload = function(){

    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('#<id_of_button>');
    btn.onclick = function (e) {

        var file = '<relative_path_to_file>.js';
        var f = document.createElement('script');

        f.onload = function(){
            // use the loaded script here if needed
        };

        f.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        f.setAttribute('src', file);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(f);
    }
}
```

Make sure to declare window.onload before the document has finished loading (if using), otherwise the code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Use attachEvent for IE8, otherwise this script should work in all 'mainstream' browsers.

```
btn.onclick = function (e) {
    // correction: the parameter that gets passed into the function
    // is an event object not the name of a file.

    var file = 'file_to_load.js';
    var f = document.createElement('script');

    f.onload = function(){
        // use the loaded script here
    };

    f.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    f.setAttribute('src', file);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function(){
    var b = document.getElementById('button'), f = 'script.js?12345';
    if(b.id == 'some-id') {
        b.onclick = function() {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            s.setAttribute('src', f);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks, I just wanted to enclose the whole function within window.onload event

Comment: I have tried both and still not working I have added the javascript file maybe it might help

Comment: @user3706227 Open a plain html file, insert the snippet from above (try the second version), make another file, let's say on the same location, name it `script.js`, write in some code, let's say `alert('hello there')`; I just tested here and all works fine.

Comment: It is finally working but  as I have added another script to call the other files using their buttons it stopped working. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @user3706227 I just tested the code adding two external .js files and all works here. If you have more than one file, you may merge them, or load them within a loop. There's no sense to multiple the snippet above.

Comment: Ok what if I wanted to add an if statement to check which button id is selected and on that basis I choose the js file to load
at this line of code var b = document.getElementById('button'), f = 'script.js?12345';

how can i do that ?